# How to set highRefreshRate in WebXR?

Tags: oculus, webxr

For WebVR I've found: vrDisplay.requestPresent ([{source: canvas, attributes: {highRefreshRate: true}}]);

For WebXR only: requiredFeatures: ["local-floor"]

For requiredFeatures: ["highRefreshRate"]. I get "Unrecognized feature requested: highRefreshRate" Error in Oculus Go. Can I get supported features?

and how to set 'foveationLevel: 3'?

Answer (score 0):

Foveation and high refresh rate features aren't specified yet AFAIK.

However if you are willing to feature-detect and handle failures, here are the strings which Oculus Browser will recognize in addition to the standard ones like `local-floor`:

- Foveation: `no-fixed-foveation`, `low-fixed-foveation-level`, `medium-fixed-foveation-level`, `high-fixed-foveation-level`
- Refresh rate: `low-refresh-rate`, `high-refresh-rate`
- Chromatic aberration correction: `ca-correction`

So for example:

```js
button.onclick = async () => {
  let session = await navigator.xr.requestSession('immersive-vr', {
    requiredFeatures: ['high-fixed-foveation-level', 'low-refresh-rate']
  });
  ...
};
```

Comment: thanks, I get 60/72 fps (16/14 ms) for low/high refresh rate on Oculus Go (but I can't see any difference yet :) at "WebXR samples" [link](https://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/webxr/samples.htm)

Comment: as expected, my demo with 'high-refresh-rate' 'requiredFeatures' doesn't work in Chrome on Android 10 (Xiaomi Mi9). It works with 'optionalFeatures' and I get ~14 ms (72 fps) on Oculus Go again. Shall I use 'optionalFeatures'?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the simplest and most future proof thing to do.